# Python: Checking for existing entries in an embedded interable

Tags: python, list, tuples, iteration

I have a tuple of tuples.  I want to iterate through each nested tuple, but I want to check to see if it's already been added to a different list (checking for duplicates based on IP). If it hasn't been added already, I want to append the contents of the whole nested tuple to the new list.

I think I know it's not doing what I intend because I need to check inside each nested tuple in the new list for the IP to see if it's duplicated, but I can't figure out how to check inside the nested elements of the new list.

```
example = (('ROUTER1', '17.2.155.224', 'WS-C3850-48T-E'),('ROUTER2', '27.24.251.212', 'WS-C3850-48T-E'),('ROUTER3', '27.24.251.212', 'WS-C3850-48T-E'))

new_list = []

for item in example:
    if item[1] in new_list:
       pass
    else:
       new_list.append(item)
        
print(new_list)
```

Comment: You could use another list called `dups` in which you will store all the IP addresses iterated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two ways to do this.

**Option 1:**

You can use list comprehension in the loop it self. This keeps the structure you currently have and does not add a new variable, but adds time complexity.

```
example = (('ROUTER1', '17.2.155.224', 'WS-C3850-48T-E'), ('ROUTER2', '27.24.251.212', 'WS-C3850-48T-E'),
           ('ROUTER3', '27.24.251.212', 'WS-C3850-48T-E'))

new_list = []

for item in example:
    if item[1] in [elm[1] for elm in new_list]:
        pass
    else:
        new_list.append(item)

print(new_list)
```

**Option 2**

This way introduces a new variable but is much faster because you aren't looping an extra set through the variable on each iteration.

```
example = (('ROUTER1', '17.2.155.224', 'WS-C3850-48T-E'), ('ROUTER2', '27.24.251.212', 'WS-C3850-48T-E'),
           ('ROUTER3', '27.24.251.212', 'WS-C3850-48T-E'))

new_list = []
found = []

for item in example:
    if item[1] in found:
        pass
    else:
        new_list.append(item)
        found.append(item[1])

print(new_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a dictionary instead of a list, so it will be easier and more efficient to check for duplicate IPs.

The dictionary keys are the IPs and the values are the tuples.

```
example = (('ROUTER1', '17.2.155.224', 'WS-C3850-48T-E'), ('ROUTER2', '27.24.251.212', 'WS-C3850-48T-E'),
           ('ROUTER3', '27.24.251.212', 'WS-C3850-48T-E'))

new_dict = dict()

for item in example:
    # Checking if an IP already been added
    if item[1] in new_dict.keys():
        pass
    else:
        # Adding a new entry to the dictionary => < IP : tuple >
        new_dict[item[1]] = item

print(new_dict.values())
```

Comment: This worked Aviv, thank you.  I selected the answer below as the solution because it didn't require me to re-work the next function I have to use a dictionary instead of a list (which in actuality is 3 lists).